# capturar inputs por la consola de chrome con javascript sin usar prompt

Tags: javascript, entrada, google-chrome, navegador-web, prompt

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en electron, utiliza un chrome por debajo,  y me gustaría capturar entradas desde la consola del navegador sin usar prompt ni readline (ya que este último se visualiza en el terminal pero no en la consola del navegador).
Sé que no tiene mucho sentido pero he estado googleando sobre todo en stackoverflow en inglés y no he encontrado ninguna solución clara que no se base en usar readline. La verdad es que me extraña que no haya una opción disponible para capturar entradas de teclado sin usar prompt en el navegador.

**Actualización 1**
En respuesta al comentario del usuario Aaronibio, he hecho un un sencillo keylogger:

```
function keylogger(){
    if (start === false){
    keyloggerChain = "";
    }
    start = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(tecla !== 13){
            keylogger();
        }else{
            console.log(`La secuencia de teclas pulsadas es ${keyloggerChain}`)
        }
    },100)
    
}
```

Para que funcione tiene que declarse las siguientes variables:

```
var keyloggerChain;
var tecla;
var start = false;
```

Además, debe añadirse el siguiente código, el cuál hace referencia a la escucha de un evento que consiste en pulsar una tecla determinada.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
    tecla = event.keyCode;
    keyloggerChain += "|" + tecla;
    console.log(keyloggerChain) //Esta línea es opcional
})
```

Aunque esta línea de solución que consiste en añadir un escuchador de eventos me parece interesante, no es lo que estoy buscando puesto que tienes que tener activa la ventana del navegador (por ejemplo haciendo click en ella), la cuál no incluye la consola del browser de chrome. En otras palabras, mientras estás escribiendo en la consola, no tienes la ventana del browser activa, no se están produciendo eventos de usuario sobre `document` entonces no se está escuchando los eventos referentes a las teclas presionadas.

Comment: ¿Has probado con una función keyup. keudown o keypress? Podrías meter todo lo recogido por ese keylogger.

Comment: @Aaronibio: Buena idea!

Comment: Osea, para que te funcione como quieres, ¿tienes que escribir FUERA del browser, en una consola a parte, y que se muestre en el browser?

Comment: @Aaronibio:Claro, yo lo que busco es la interacción con la consola del browser únicamente y no con la página en sí.